# How to pass values between two SherlockFragment?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a SherlockFragmentActivity with two SherlockFragment in ActionBar.

In each SherlockFragment I ask for several values to user like Step 1 and Step 2 task. In Step 2 Fragment, I have a button that calls webMethod in order to do action but for this webMethod I need all values that user introduced in Step 1 & 2 Fragments.

What is the best practice to pass or get the Step 1 fragment values in Step 2 fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass values between Fragments through your `SherlockFragmentActivity`. The main idea is to create an interface and make your activity implement this one to pass data from fragmentA to Activity and from this one to your other fragmentB.

Check out [Communicating with activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) and [Creating event callbacks to the activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) in Android docs for more detailed information.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `Bundle` Object and put Values in the bundle and pass that to next fragment using `setArguments()`.

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("myString","String Value");
b.putInt("myInt",9);
yourFragment.setArguments(b);
```

Then you retrieve the same in Second Fragment as

```
Bundle b = getArguments();
String myStringFromFirstFragment = b.getString("myString");
int myIntFromFirstFragment = b.getInt("myInt");
```